# Cómo obtener el tamaño de @Param en @Query Repositories JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, java-8, jpql

tengo una duda y es que quiero saber el tamaño de un **@Param** que le paso a la **@Query** pero me da el siguiente error al compilar:

```
unexpected token: : near line 1
```

les muestro el codigo de mi consulta:

```
  @Query(
  value = "SELECT DISTINCT company "
      + " FROM Company company "
      + " left join  company.companyProducts products "
      + " inner join  empresa.servicios services "
      + "   WHERE services.idService IN (:idsServices) "
      + "   AND products.id.idProduct IS NOT NULL "
      + "   AND ( (:idsProducts IS NOT NULL AND  COUNT(:idsProducts)>0)"
      + ") OR productos.id.idProduct IN (:idsProducts)) ")
  List<EmpresaGrupo> obtenerEmpresasProductoServicio(@Param("idsProducts") List<Integer> 
  idsProducts,
  @Param("idsServices") List<Integer> idsServices);
```

El error salta justo donde hago el conteo del @Param:

```
(:idsProducts IS NOT NULL AND  COUNT(:idsProducts)>0)
```

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: el count se compara con > que 0? o es toda la linea? estaba analizando el orden de los paréntesis y cuenta el idsProducts  sin embargo el >0 esta en el paréntesis externo

Comment: Hola buenas,si se compara con >0, en el codigo se me pasó un (,quedaría así AND ( (:idsProducts IS NOT NULL AND  COUNT(:idsProducts)>0)"
      + "OR productos.id.idProduct IN (:idsProducts),disculpe

Comment: y eso soluciono el problema?

Comment: No, al final tuve que quitar el count.

Answer (score 1):

hay un paréntesis de cierre  en la linea del @query que notaras que cierra el script por lo que debes cerrar bien, recuerda que primero cierra internamente del mas interno al mas externo.

```
@Query(
  value = "SELECT DISTINCT company "
      + " FROM Company company "
      + " left join  company.companyProducts products "
      + " inner join  empresa.servicios services "
      + "   WHERE services.idService IN (:idsServices) "
      + "   AND products.id.idProduct IS NOT NULL "
      + "   AND ((:idsProducts IS NOT NULL AND  COUNT(:idsProducts)>0)"
      + " OR productos.id.idProduct IN (:idsProducts)) ")
  List<EmpresaGrupo> obtenerEmpresasProductoServicio(@Param("idsProducts") List<Integer> 
  idsProducts,
  @Param("idsServices") List<Integer> idsServices);
```